# Undergrad in QFT/GR looking to do string theory Ph.D

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, string-theory, soft-question, education

I am currently a third year undergrad in physics who is currently taking QFT and GR. I took these classes just out of pure interest in the subjects but I find that my mind is being blown almost every lecture and I am immensely enjoying these classes.

I have talked to my professors and graduate students about doing research in string theory and I have realized that I would like to end up doing a Ph.D in Physics, specializing in string theory.

I am not having too much trouble in terms of the math for my QFT and GR classes yet but I have learned that for string theory it is required to learn much higher level maths like topology, differential forms, homology, cohomology.

**MY QUESTION:**

I realize my mathematical background is lacking a bit in terms of higher math that is required for string theory and I am just wondering what is expected (in terms of mathematical background) of an undergrad who is to be accepted for a graduate study in string theory? Also do you think if I devoted all of my time to it that I could eventually learn all of this maths?

Comment: >Also do you think if I devoted all of my time to it that I could eventually learn all of this maths? Plenty do.

Comment: In less than 1 year?

Comment: That obviously depends on you and your ability, but one would expect that a standard undergrad course would prepare you for a standard graduate course :)

Comment: What exactly is a standard undergrad and standard grad?

Comment: If your professor thinks that you can do it, then he/she will accept you. If he/she thinks that it's beyond your capability then you won't get into the program. It's your professor's decision to make.

Comment: So are you saying there is nothing specifically I can do to prepare to maximize my chances?

Comment: It really depends on the specific type of string theory you do. I think rather than obsessing over learning specific mathematical topics which may or may not be useful, it's better to just open up Polchinski, or GSW and start reading them. When an unfamiliar mathematical concept comes up, they'll usually explain it and its physical relevance. If that doesn't satisfy you, you can then open up mathematical texts and go into more detail. Most importantly this will give you a good idea of what's useful and what isn't. Just because people say "topology" is useful in string theory (it is) doesn't...

Comment: ... necessarily mean reading Munkres or Hatcher cover to cover is the best use of your time (it isn't). I tried this approach for a while, taking graduate-level pure math courses and what not thinking it'll be useful for string theory, and it didn't help much. Mainly because the way these concepts are applied in physics and the way physicists think about them is very different from how mathematicians present them. So in short, don't worry about math in advance. If you understand QFT and GR well enough, you can start reading string theory texts and pick up the math as you need it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have polchinski's book and I am attempting to read through it. How do I communicate to my potential advisors when I apply next year that I have an immense amount of interest in the subject and would be an ideal canidate for doing research in string theory?

Comment: Are there any string theorists or people who do research in closely related areas at your current institute? If so, the best way would be to undertake either a research project or a reading course related in some way to string theory under the supervision of one of those professors. In that case if you perform well, you won't be the only one professing your interest and ability, but you'll also have letter writers doing it for you, which is immensely helpful.

Comment: In case you find that no string theorist is willing to supervise you or you have access to none at your institute, I would highly recommend that you try working in some other theoretical area. Modern research in CMT, or particle theory for example. The point is not to constrain yourself unnecessarily. Some research is better than none at all, which is often the case for people who only want to do string theory, since the learning curve to do research is really steep. I'd also imagine that since you say you've been generally enjoying QFT and GR, other areas of theory might also appeal to you.

Comment: In fact my QFT professor is doing research in string theory but im scared to ask him to do research with him, being an undergraduate. I feel like he won't take my request seriously at all.